# AWS ELB create 5XX when scale in and out and how to filtering this alert

Tags: amazon-web-services, notifications

I'm receiving email when 5XX error occurs, and I do not want to receiving email when ELB creates 5XX error because of scale in and out. I would like to know how to do this.

updated
I added a part of email

```
You are receiving this email because your Amazon CloudWatch Alarm “elb-was-Really-High-Sum-HTTP-5XXs" in the US East (N. Virginia) region has entered the ALARM state, because "Threshold Crossed: 1 datapoint [239.0 (08/01/20 01:51:00)] was greater than or equal to the threshold (120.0)." at "Wednesday 08 January, 2020 01:52:25 UTC".

View this alarm in the AWS Management Console:
```

Comment: Who is sending you these emails? AWS?

Comment: @ceejayoz yes it seems like alarm was made in ec2 console

Comment: Could you share a sample of the email you received?

Comment: @ceejayoz I added a sample.

Comment: This looks like a standard CloudWatch alarm. You should be able to delete or modify it in the CloudWatch console.